# unity failed Build android : could not resolve all files

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hello im new in Unity and Im tryin to build android but its failed
heres my spec :

- JDK 1.8.0_144
- Android NDK R-19
- Gradle 6.1.1

and heres the error

[image: Build Failure]

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unityLibrary:releaseCompileClasspath'.
       > Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
          > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar.
             > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 32s
    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: are you using the Android Resolver package? if so, does it resolve without any problems? can you provide resolver logs?

Comment: Resolution succeeded, but build still failed.. how can we check resolver log ?

Comment: are you using custom gradle files? do you have jetifier and androidX enabled? `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true`